# In memory of the Yellow CSS Box

Tags: feature-request, design, blockquote

Oh yellow box of error
How I miss your background hue
Parsing your words of terror
From the many to the few

> Now replaced by a simple line
> That's vertical and grey
> A designer thought it fine
> But to me it caused dismay

I used to Edit questions so
Your yellow box would appear
Instead I'll give my nose a blow
And in memory shed a tear

> From afar it's now all a blur
> And the quotes are hard to track
> They were so easy to infer
> Can we change the colour back?
>
> [<sub>Scratte</sub>](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394516/in-memory-of-the-yellow-css-box#comment759299_394516)

Comment: You should have used a yellow box for this ...

Comment: [The colour should be changed to blue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344909/change-the-colour-of-quotes-to-blue)

Comment: I am also already missing the yellow box

Comment: From afar it's now all a blur. And the quotes are hard to track. They were so easy to infer. Can we change the colour back?

Comment: In raiment gold the box did stand, then guided by an unseen hand. Behold a quest to bring it back, new life to breathe upon our Stack.

Comment: 1. Website changes something. 2. Users dislike the change. 3. User wants the change reverted, but doesn't provide a reason why one is better than the other. 4...?

Comment: @Cerbrus In response to 3: I'm not convinced that this poetry is subtle enough that it requires reading between the lines. I cannot speak for everyone, so **I** liked the "background hue" and find it better than "a simple line". **I** also don't like that "quotes are hard to track", but I much prefer that they're "easy to infer". I'd think those were reasons.

Comment: All I see there is a personal preference and a user not taking a moment to get used to a changed design, as is very common with design changes on websites.

Comment: This change was so earth-shattering, it made me log back in for the first time in nearly 3 months.

Comment: @BoltClock you were so confused you first had to post an answer? ;) Welcome back!

Comment: @Cerbrus related reason: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/343923/287976, https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/344849/287976 and  https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/343921/287976. None of them had been addressed by SE as declined and why, which gives a feeling of "we'll do as we want anyway"

Comment: @Tensibai: Those answers don't provide strong arguments other than a personal preference.

Comment: @Cerbrus They're more supported than the announcement itself... which makes me feel the general preference goes that way. I won't die on this hill anyway but I also missed parts of answers were quotes without background text and it made me wonders why two paragraph in the same post were antagonists until realizing the first was a quote from another answer I hadn't read yet.

Comment: @Tensibai: SE isn't exactly an democracy, though. Now, i'm not saying this change is good or bad, it's just that other than the usual backlash large websites get against design changes, I'm not seeing any good arguments to revert that change...

Comment: @Cerbrus It was dead easy to see quotes at a glance before due to the entire block being shaded but now it is definitely not as simple. How is this not reason enough? In fact I might just going to write a userscript to revert it back myself.

Comment: @Taazar: I'm not having any trouble spotting quote blocks, and I honestly think they look better now. See how it's still just personal opinions that are being voiced here?

Comment: @Cerbrus Let's agree to disagree then. The links I gave on MSE doesn't look like backlash to me but request to review the change with improvements to make blockquotes more obvious than the actual state with just a bar on the left. A light border around could be an idea too. Giving a personal feeling *and* ideas to improve doesn't sounds backlash to me. (not talking about this poem here, but it has the merit of reopening the talk ?)

Comment: @Tensibai: My criticism is on _this_ question.

Comment: @Cerbrus I was answering your comment saying: "Those answers don't provide strong arguments other than a personal preference." <= that's on this one that I disagree. And my initial comment was to counter a bit the general "doesn't provide a reason".

Comment: I simply found the Yellow Box as a great way to highlight _error messages_, rather than using code blocks (which don't wrap).

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I find error messages unreadable when they're wordwrapped. So I'm more likely to avoid those Questions.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein: Error messages are usually more readable when they're formatted in a (`<!-- langugage: lang-none -->`) code block.

Comment: Mobile site still has the delicate but effective yellow box, which makes comparing  "yesterday's" block quotes with today's gray bar easier. And... there's no question I prefer the former, the quotes just stand out better.

Comment: For those wanting to give the "designers" a piece of your mind: [some-"impovements"-to-blockquotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/343919/some-improvements-to-blockquotes/343946#comment1156292_343946)

Comment: I see that now blockquotes are highlighted without highlighting, well done...